# Inserir dados em um Json Externo

Tags: javascript, jquery, banco-de-dados, json, aplicação-web

Como insiro dados em um arquivo Json externo:

```
var json = 
{
  caminho: "img/minhaIMG.png",
  descricao: "minha descricão"
}
```

Como posso inserir novos dados nesse arquivo json? No meu caso, usaria o mesmo como um "Banco de dados" dos meus arquivos.

Após criar o objJSON no meu javascript, como posso inseri-lo no meu arquivo?

Comment: Herinque, conforme dito pelo zidnd, javascript não pode realizar operações de escrita/leitura no lado do cliente, te aconselho usar localstorage ou sessionstorage para armazenar dados no lado do cliente caso este realmente seja seu intuito

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues ...é Zignd... e não zidnd... :P

Comment: @Zignd isto! rsrs

Comment: agradeço a resposta, na minha concepção entendia que poderia fazer isto diretamente com o javascript, havia me esquecido que isto partia para o lado do server, agradeço o esclarecimento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript, quando utilizado pelo navegador, não pode realizar operações de escrita ou leitura livremente no sistema de arquivos do sistema operacional.

O que você poderia fazer é montar uma aplicação web com alguma tecnologia *server-side*, como ASP.NET MVC ou PHP por exemplo, e através dessa aplicação você realizar as operações de escrita nesse arquivo JSON, note também esse arquivo estará no lado do servidor e não no lado do cliente.

Caso você queira armazenar e manipular esse arquivo JSON no lado do cliente você pode utilizar a API File que permite que sua aplicação interaja com arquivos locais em um sistema de arquivos virtuais, ou seja, você terá acesso a um diretório que será apenas da sua aplicação, dentro desse diretório você poderá realizar quais quer operações que desejar, mas não poderá sair de dentro dele para acessar o sistema de arquivos do sistema operacional.

Para saber mais sobre as tecnologias *server-side* que mencionei acima, recomendo que você dê uma olhada wiki do site para as tags ASP.NET MVC e PHP:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-mvc/info
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

E para saber mais sobre a API File recomendo os artigos abaixo:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API/Introduction
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/